# RoR scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a users table.  It contains a field "user_type".
I added the following scope stmts to the user.rb file:

```
scope :uemployee, where(:user_type => 'employee')
scope :uclient, where(:user_type => 'client')
scope :ucontractor, where(:user_type => 'contractor')
```

I created a view and I would like it to list he employees.
Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
 <% @users.uemployee.each do |user| %>
```

But, I get "undefined method `uemployee' for nil:NilClass"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the orm?  belongs_to :client
  has_many :assigned_worequests, :class_name => "worequest", :foreign_key => "employee_id"
  has_many :worequests
  has_many :statuses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you wanted to do this:

```
<% User.uemployee.each do |user| %>
```

But this is considered to be a bad practice. You have to prepare you data in a controller and a view just cycles through it:

```
# in a controller's action
@users = User.uemployee

#in a view
<% @users.uemployee.each do |user| %>
```

But even this isn't the best approach. If you create the file `views/users/_user.html.erb` which shows the info about a particular user (current user will be available as a simple `user` variable, without the `@`) then you can simply write:

```
# in a view
<%= render @users %>
# remember, @users variable was set in your controller
```

then Rails will cycle through all the users "inside" the `@users` variable and show them one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@users` collection is nil